# Converting structured flat array to tree object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an unsolved problem with my script, I have Array of **FlatObj** and some rule, i need to write **converter** function to **TreeObj**.

Rules:

- Adjacent higher **depth** will be a child of adjacent lower **depth**
- "ROOT" will be start of **TreeObj**

```
interface FlatObj {
  id: String;
  depth: number;
}

interface TreeObj {
  id: String;
  children?: TreeObj[];
}

const data: FlatObj[] = [
  {
    id: "ROOT",
    depth: 0
  },
  {
    id: "G1",
    depth: 1
  },
  {
    id: "G2",
    depth: 1
  },
  {
    id: "G2-1",
    depth: 2
  },
  {
    id: "G2-2",
    depth: 2
  },
  {
    id: "G2-2-1",
    depth: 3
  },
  {
    id: "G3",
    depth: 1
  }
];

const converter = (data: FlatObj[]): TreeObj => {
  // converting FlatObj to TreeObj ...
}
```

The result should look like this

```json
{
  id: "ROOT",
  children: [
    { id: "G1" },
    {
      id: "G2",
      children: [
        { id: "G2-1" },
        {
          id: "G2-2",
          children: [ { id: "G2-2-1" } ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { id: "G3" },
  ]
}
```

I don't have any really good ideas for it, Any idea help to solve this problem will be apprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a helper array for the latest level of depth.

```js
const 
    data = [{ id: "ROOT", depth: 0 }, { id: "G1", depth: 1 }, { id: "G2", depth: 1 }, { id: "G2-1", depth: 2 }, { id: "G2-2", depth: 2 }, { id: "G2-2-1", depth: 3 }, { id: "G3", depth: 1 }],
    tree = [],
    levels = [tree];

data.forEach(({ id, depth }) => levels[depth].push({ id, children: levels[depth + 1] = [] }));

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A version without having empty children arrays.

```js
const 
    data = [{ id: "ROOT", depth: 0 }, { id: "G1", depth: 1 }, { id: "G2", depth: 1 }, { id: "G2-1", depth: 2 }, { id: "G2-2", depth: 2 }, { id: "G2-2-1", depth: 3 }, { id: "G3", depth: 1 }],
    tree = [],
    levels = [tree];

data.forEach(({ id, depth }) => {
    (levels[depth] ??= levels[depth-1].at(-1).children = []).push({ id });
    levels[depth + 1] = undefined;
});

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey bro, sorry but I can't converting above code to typescript. Can you help me? thanks.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea of typescript.